# What is the meaning of randomize and populate the dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have been given an imbalanced dataset and asked to implement functions to 1/ randomize the data 2/populate the training and validation data.
does it mean to randomly shuffle the data and then split it into training and validation sets?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would say that is what the Question asks of you. As the dataset is imbalanced, make sure you stratify (unless there is a reason not to, e.g time series).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The main purpose of that is to get more stratified training and validation sets. That is the simplest method to handle imbalanced datasets.